# Vaultwarden hardening

Tags: iptables, cloudflare

I’ve been to harden my security around the vaultwarden instance and currently unable to get the iptables working. The ban on Cloudflares side is working fine, although for some reason the iptables will never block the requests.

I have the following action defined to block the connection, since CFs firewalls need a bit longer to update and block the request.

```
[Definition]

actionban = ip6tables -I INPUT -m string --algo bm --string 'Cf-Connecting-Ip: <ip>' -j DROP
actionunban = ip6tables -D INPUT -m string --algo bm --string 'Cf-Connecting-Ip: <ip>' -j DROP
```

This definition triggers and is set in the iptables, but doesn’t block the attacker IP, they are able to continue the brute force until the firewall is updated on CF’s end and blocks the connection. There are no error logs indicating there is something misconfigured, the IP in the iptables is also correct.

I'm using cloudflare tunnel to expose my service to the public.

Comment: This is confusing. The config you've shown us looks like it came from fail2ban yet you never mention fail2ban.Either there is a lot more to this story than you are telling us here or you are completely off target. This config is not going to block connections - it might mangle some.